# How to addDomListener for multiple Google Maps on a page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How would I go about re-centering map markers where there are multiple maps on a single page? I have this script that I created which works as expected, I have all individual maps on the page with each map having it's own marker, this works as expected.

The problem I'm running into is that my addDomListener is only working on the last map on my page.

This is example HTML of code I'm using to dynamically generate the maps.

```
<div id="map0" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="42.997394" data-lng="-78.180130">
<div id="map1" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="41.997394" data-lng="-76.180130">
<div id="map2" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="40.997394" data-lng="-74.180130">
```

This is the Javascript that I'm currently using:

```
function initMap() {

    var locations = [];

    // Get All Maps By Class Name
    var mapEl = document.getElementsByClassName("google-map");

    // For each map push data attribute to locations array
    $(mapEl).each(function() {
        var arr = [];
        arr.push(parseFloat(this.dataset.lat));
        arr.push(parseFloat(this.dataset.lng));
        locations.push(arr)
    });

    // Loop through each location and generate map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var latlng = {lat: locations[i][0], lng: locations[i][1]};

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            zoom: 14,
            zoomControl: false,
            styles: mapBrand
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

    }

    var center = map.getCenter();

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        map.setCenter(center);
    });

}
```

How would go about being able to center the marker for individual map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep references to all the maps and the center required for each, then process through those (set the center for each map).

```
// keep reference to map and center
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + i), mapOptions);
maps.push({map: map, center: map.getCenter()});

// process through all the maps, setting the center
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
    maps[i].map.setCenter(maps[i].center);
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/y7cLa9co/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var locations = [];
  var maps = [];
  // Get All Maps By Class Name
  var mapEl = document.getElementsByClassName("google-map");

  // For each map push data attribute to locations array
  $(mapEl).each(function() {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(parseFloat(this.dataset.lat));
    arr.push(parseFloat(this.dataset.lng));
    locations.push(arr)
  });

  // Loop through each location and generate map
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var latlng = {
      lat: locations[i][0],
      lng: locations[i][1]
    };

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: false,
      // styles: mapBrand
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + i), mapOptions);
    maps.push({
      map: map,
      center: map.getCenter()
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    });
  }

  var center = map.getCenter();

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
      maps[i].map.setCenter(maps[i].center);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#map0,
#map1,
#map2 {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map0" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="42.997394" data-lng="-78.180130"></div>
<div id="map1" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="41.997394" data-lng="-76.180130"></div>
<div id="map2" class="google-map archive-map" data-lat="40.997394" data-lng="-74.180130"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. For whatever reason I'm getting the following console error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: if you are loading the API asynchronously (`&callback=initMap async defer`), you don't need the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);` in my code.

Comment: Ahh, i see makes sense. Is it better to not use the callback and do it how you listed?

Comment: research `async defer` (that is how google is now doing all their examples)

Comment: Is there any reason why there would be a delay for the window resize event on mobile device when you change orientation? It seems like the maps do not readjust themselves until you scroll up or down on the device.